# Differential amplifier solving equations for iDS

Tags: math

In large signal analysis of differential amplifier there are some equations  to determine iDS.

If we simplify it looks like that :

\$ \large 2x^2+2kx+k^2-2\frac{l}{m}=o\$

Is there an easy way to solve these kind of equations. What should one study to easily solve these kind of problems?

**Edit**

Original equation looks like this.

[image: Signal analysis of differential amplifier]

Citation :

> Agarwal, Anant, Lang, Jeffrey. Foundations of Analog and Digital
>   Electronic Circuits.. [edx].

**Edit**

Ok. I solved equation using completing the square technic.

\$ \large (x+\frac{k}{2})^2 = \frac {l} {m} - \frac{k^2}{4}\$

\$ \large x = \frac{1}{2}(\frac {\sqrt {4l-mk^2}}{\sqrt{m}} - k) \$

Comment: Looks like a simple quadratic equation to me (assuming `x` is the unknown). Grade 6 or so....

Comment: Algebra 101...,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off topic.

Comment: I don't think so. Because sometimes mathematics and physics are necessary to understand theory and very useful in engineering courses. Is it possible to analyze an RC circuit without differential equations?

Comment: @Erdem -- there's a subtraction operation in the equation.  Perhaps that should break out into it's own question??

Comment: I am surprised to learn that most of my problem-solving problems are with
mathematics rather than my understanding of theory. I try to identify the areas where I have difficulty solving the problem. Many times, my actual deficiencies are in my understanding and ability to use certain mathematical principles. For now I watch some videos about differential equations and work some example problems in that videos. Sometimes solving a Bernoulli differential equation looks easier to me rather than solving these kinds of quadratic equations.